# Execute chain of functions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, data-processing

I am doing data pre-processing using Python and Pandas. For that reason, I wrote several functions for cleaning data, which should be executed one after another in sequence.

I don't want to manually execute all functions every time I open Jupyter. So I am searching for something similar to a trigger, where I will include all function names and by initializing it, all functions will be executed.

One way is to define a Python function which will call other functions inside body; but not sure how efficient is that.

I looked for `sklearn.Pipeline()` and `pandas.pipe()` functions, but none of those seemed right tool for me.

Any recommendations?

Comment: "One way is to define a Python function which will call other functions inside body; but not sure how efficient is that." Yeah that's the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Write a driver function - lets call it `start()` and call all your data cleaning functions one after the other in this function.

```
def start():
    data_cleaning_1()
    data_cleaning_2()
    data_cleaning_3()
    .
    .
```

Call the `start()` function.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by storing the reference to the functions on a list, but create a new function that call all those functions makes more sense.

```
def fun1():
    print("function 1")
def fun2():
    print("function 2")

functions = [fun1,fun2]

for function in functions:
    function()
```

or

```
def fun1():
    print("function 1")
def fun2():
    print("function 2")

def begin():
    func1()
    func2()
    # any other function 

begin()
```

If you want something more advanced, you could use the design pattern Chain of Responsibility [reading material](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility)